# Position an element at top right of a <span> in IE

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble positioning a (div) element at the top right of a span. It works in FF3, but not in IE7:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
body
{
    font-size: 24px;
}

.tag
{
    padding: 3px;
    background-color: lightblue;
    position: relative;
}

.x
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: orange;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
text <span class="tag">tag<div class="x"></div></span> text 
</body>
</html>
```

In FF3, a 10x10 orange box is rendered at the top right corner of the light blue box. I am having trouble getting this to work in IE7. Thanks!

Comment: did you mean ie6 because i tried your code in ie7 and it works well!

Comment: Positioning at the top left seems to work in both browsers -- it only breaks when positioning at the right side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, get a proper doctype for your page so that it's not rendered in quirks mode.

[W3C: Recommended list of DTDs](http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html)

Second, make sure that the code is valid. You can not put a block element (div) inside an inline element (span).

[W3C markup validation](http://validator.w3.org/)

Comment: Adding the xhtml1-strict.dtd DTD fixed my problem. Thanks. As far as not putting divs inside spans, what would be the recommended way to position a box at the top right of an inline span?

Comment: Use a span tag in the markup, and display:block in the css to make it a block element.

Answer (score 0):

you can also see this [post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533005.aspx) if you have trouble with positionning in IE7 in the future